# How to manipulate data through postman with spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring

Following are request payload in postman:

```
{
"name":"xyz",
"usename":"xyz@123",
"address":{
  "street":{
  "locations":[{
     "lng":-12.2342,
     "lat":23.1234
  },
   {
    "lng":-12.2342,
    "lat":23.1234
   },
   {
    "lng":-12.2342,
    "lat":23.1234
    }]
  }
 }
}
```

and i have database schema like

```
id(pk)string
name String
username String
geometry String
```

in above schema geometry field contains array of lng/lat in string format

like `polygon(-12.2342 23.1234,-12.2342 23.1234,-12.2342 23.1234)`

so how can i convert above request payload array of lat/lng to string type so that i can store it in mysql database like data `polygon(-12.2342 23.1234,-12.2342 23.1234,-12.2342 23.1234)` with springboot?

Comment: Do you use jpa or sql to store/map date to DB?

Comment: @lczapski,I am using Jpa with hibernate and spring boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Call location in payload as locations because its array:
2. Have entities like below:

```java
    class Location{

       double long;
       double lat;

    }

    class Street {
      List<Location> locations; 
    }

    class Address {
       Street street; 
    }

    class RequestData {
      String name;

      String userName;

     Address address;
    }
```